# removing google custom search from my site

Tags: php, javascript, search

i have removed the below code from my website.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/cse/brand?form=cse-search-box&lang=en"></script>
```

but, in url the below code is appearing.

```
&Search1.x=0&Search1.y=0
```

how to remove it?

Answer (score 1):

You use `<input type="image" .../>` to submit the form? Change it to submit button or use javascript to submit the form.

Comment: iam using jquery autocomplete function in this site. but, it is not working. does it effect the working of autocomplete?

Comment: @user1500453 No, no relation.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off `register_globals`

To turn register globals off, you will need to change the settings in the php.ini file to:

`register_globals = Off` (Note the upper case letter O in Off)

This will prevent [PHP from automatically turning any value in the URL into a variable](http://plus84ga.blogspot.com/2012/07/php-from-automatically-turning-any.html). That's a good thing because it means that hackers cannot try to insert anything they want into your code simply by inserting it into your URL. Well written code should be validating the variables anyway, but this provides extra security in case the script does not validate variables properly or if the validation is buggy.